# Why does my particular solution to $y''-y'-2y=2e^{-t}$ via variation of parameters not match that by undetermined coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The particular solution to $y''-y'-2y=2e^{-t}$ found by the method of undetermined coefficients is $Y(t)=-\frac{2}{3}te^{-t}$

However, when I find the particular solution via the method of variation of parameters I obtain a different expression.  I would really appreciate someone to point out where my calculations go awry.

First I find the fundamental set of solutions for the analogous homogeneous equation $y''-y'-2y=0$ which are $y_1(t)=e^{-t}$ and $y_2(t)=e^{2t}$.  Then I use these to find the Wronskian $W(y_1,y_2)(t)=3e^t$.  Then I plug these values into the following equation to get the particular solution:

$$Y(t)=-y_1(t)\int \frac{y_2(t)g(t)}{W(y_1,y_2)(t)}dt+y_2(t)\int\frac{y_1(t)g(t)}{W(y_1,y_2)(t)}dt$$
Where $g(t)=2e^{-t}$ is the non-homogeneous term.

$$Y(t)=-e^{-t}\int\frac{e^{2t}2e^{-t}}{3e^t}dt+e^{2t}\int\frac{e^{-t}2e^{-t}}{3e^t}dt$$
$$=-e^{-t}\int\frac{2e^t}{3e^t}dt+e^{2t}\int\frac{2e^{-2t}}{3e^t}dt$$
$$=-e^{-t}\int\frac23dt+e^{2t}\int\frac23e^{-3t}dt$$
Finally giving:
$$Y(t)=-\frac23te^{-t}-\frac29e^{-t}$$

So why doesn't this particular solution match the one obtained from undetermined coefficients?

Comment: Every solution of the DE (and you have shown us two) is a "particular solution".  Why should different methods give you the same one?  As you showed here: they may not give you the same one.  In fact, if you use your Wronskian method, and keep the "+C" terms in the integrals, you will get the general solution of the DE.

Comment: I guess I'm confused because the textbook says I should check my work by finding the particular solution via both methods.

Comment: @FrankGallagher: Notice that you have as part of the homogeneous solution $c_1 e^{-t}$. The $-\dfrac29e^{-t}$ gets added to that and just called $c_1 e^{-t}$. After all, the $-\dfrac 29$ is also just a constant.

Comment: Oh thank you!  I didn't realize you could add that into the general solution of the homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that you have as part of the homogeneous solution $c_1 e^{-t}$.

The $-\dfrac29e^{-t}$ gets added to that and just called $c_1 e^{-t}$.

After all, the $-\dfrac 29$ is also just a constant.